# getElementsByTagName is not returning all child nodes

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, getelementsbytagname

My XML string is

```
str = "<ROOT><CATEGORY_AREA_LIST><CATEGORY_AREA NAME='General'><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='MOC'><PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='3'></PROPOSED_LEVEL></CATEGORY_TYPE><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='General'><PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='3'></PROPOSED_LEVEL></CATEGORY_TYPE></CATEGORY_AREA><CATEGORY_AREA NAME='BOO'><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='Open'><PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='1'></PROPOSED_LEVEL></CATEGORY_TYPE><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='NOC'><PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='5'></PROPOSED_LEVEL></CATEGORY_TYPE></CATEGORY_AREA></CATEGORY_AREA_LIST></ROOT>"
```

And In javascript function I am trying to get all CATEGORY_AREA

```
var dp = new DOMParser();    
  var xmlDoc = dp.parseFromString(str , "text/xml");
    var list = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CATEGORY_AREA_LIST");
    var categoryArea = list[0].childNodes;
```

But categoryArea is having only one entry.

Am I doing anything wrong?

My intention is to access all category_area and then all category_type and proposed_level.

Please help

Comment: Your XML is invalid, your assignment to the variable `str` is missing the `=`, and `dp` is undefined. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete information, Due to copy pasting it got missed. I have edited my question. Please help me.

Comment: What is the problem is my XML? could you please explain?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/393kXaq.png

Comment: On top of what @Quentin said, if you use a method like parseFromString, you need to have a basic understanding of how it works.  I can't imagine that, if you had bothered to read a single thing about how it works, you wouldn't know that it returns error documents when there is a problem.  This is the first thing you should've checked and it would've told you immediately that your XML is invalid.

Comment: Thank you, I have modified the xml string, still the same problem is occurring

Answer (score 1):

If you add `console.log(xmlDoc)` to your code, you can look at the XML document generated by the DOM Parser.

[image: Screenshot of DOM in browser developer tools]

It has a bunch of errors so `CATEGORY_AREA_LIST` element has no child nodes.

You can use a tool like [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) (which comes with libxml so is easily installable on most UNIX systems (including [Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10))) to highlight the specific errors in your XML.

---

Re edit:

Now you have fixed your XML, I cannot reproduce the problem:

```js
str = "<ROOT><CATEGORY_AREA_LIST><CATEGORY_AREA NAME='General'><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='MOC'><PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='3'></PROPOSED_LEVEL></CATEGORY_TYPE><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='General'><PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='3'></PROPOSED_LEVEL></CATEGORY_TYPE></CATEGORY_AREA><CATEGORY_AREA NAME='BOO'><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='Open'><PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='1'></PROPOSED_LEVEL></CATEGORY_TYPE><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='NOC'><PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='5'></PROPOSED_LEVEL></CATEGORY_TYPE></CATEGORY_AREA></CATEGORY_AREA_LIST></ROOT>"
var dp = new DOMParser();    
var xmlDoc = dp.parseFromString(str , "text/xml");
var list = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CATEGORY_AREA_LIST");
var categoryArea = list[0].childNodes;
console.log(categoryArea.length)
```

Comment: Thank you, This XML data is coming from webservice.
<ROOT><CATEGORY_AREA_LIST><CATEGORY_AREA NAME='General'><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='MOC'><PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='3'><\/PROPOSED_LEVEL><\/CATEGORY_TYPE><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='General'><PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='3'><\/PROPOSED_LEVEL><\/CATEGORY_TYPE><\/CATEGORY_AREA><CATEGORY_AREA NAME='BOO'><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='Open'><PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='1'><\/PROPOSED_LEVEL><\/CATEGORY_TYPE><CATEGORY_TYPE NAME='NOC'>\t<PROPOSED_LEVEL NAME='5'><\/PROPOSED_LEVEL><\/CATEGORY_TYPE><\/CATEGORY_AREA><\/CATEGORY_AREA_LIST><\/ROOT>,

Comment: @javaGuy — What a lot of ```\``` characters that are making it invalid XML. You should get them to fix the service.

Comment: So, if you notice, there is forward slash for every backslash , and it is getting passed to parseFromString method

Comment: How can I modify it? webservice call is giving me this output.

Comment: You talk to the people who created the web service. It's a straight-up bug. Failing that, you're going to have to try to fix the errors are you get the XML, which is an ugly, error-prone business.